# Weird DOM Behaviour when appending "input"

Tags: javascript, dom

Adding an Element to the DOM in Javascript is done like this

```
    var but =document.createElement('input');
    document.getElementById("Area").appendChild(but);
```

This transforms this div

```
<div id="Area">
    </div>
```

into this div

```
 <div id="Area">
   <input>
        </div>
```

I want it to be transformed to this div

```
  <div id="Area">
       <input> </input>
            </div>
```

This works with all other kind of strings but not "input" , so it works with "button","div","input27",..

Why is this happening?

Comment: `<input> </input>` is invalid HTML! What are you really trying to achieve? Just `<input>` is fine, and probably what you want... To give the input a value, use the `value` attribute (`<input value="text inside input">`)

Comment: I wanted to parse the html document into an XML Object and traverse the Object using XPath. Is this the only exception when using append? Why is this just the case when using "input"?

Comment: HTML is not XML, in some cases the closing tag is optional (`<p>` and `<li>` at least used to be like that), and in some other cases it's forbidden (`<input>`, `<img>` and probably others that I can't remember). If you need valid XML, use `<input/>`.

Comment: *DOM is not HTML.* When you create an element, and add it to the DOM, *there is no HTML involved*. What you're looking at if you use `.innerHTML`, is the result of an analysis of the DOM, rendered as an HTML serialization. If you don't like the HTML serialization you're getting, then just write your own.

Comment: So the best way to transform my DOM Element into XML would be to manually add to the .innerHTML the missing closed tags that do not get added using the Browsers HTML serialization.

Comment: Here, I wrote a short DOM to HTML serializer. It's very basic, but it gives closing tags to all elements. http://jsfiddle.net/xbMym/

Comment: Thank you for the extra work! I consider this as my answer. You can write it and I will mark it!